# Number of ways to put less balls in more boxes,

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Consider the simple problem of placing four coloured balls: red, blue, green and white in 15 boxes. What are the numbers of distinct ways in which the balls can be placed in these
boxes if each box can hold only one ball? Also, write the generalized formula of this
numerical result.

I am rather not sure, whether to do it with simple permutation, or I need something else. The generalized formula bit confuses me as well.

Comment: perhaps solve a smaller scale problem first?

Comment: Choose $4$ boxes and then arrange $4$ balls in those chosen boxes. To arrange balls in $4$ chosen boxes, it is equivalent to number of ways to arrange $4$ balls in a row.

Comment: I believe you are right in that a simple permutation will suffice. The generalized formula is asking to find the number of distinct ways to put $k$ colored balls (each of different colors) into $n$ boxes